# Is it possible to eliminate private key attack vector when using JWTs for authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, encryption-asymmetric

I envision the following authentication scheme with JWT:

- client authenticates against a `/login` API endpoint with `{ userName, password }`
- server verifies userName+password against the stored hashed credentials and issues a JWT token with a set of claims, signs that with a private key
- client then uses the issued JWT token to authenticate any subsequent calls to the API while server verifies the token and applies authorization rules based solely on claims present in the presented token (statelessly)

The signing key must be stored on server, and it creates a very valuable attack vector.

The potential attacker who obtains access to the private key can generate a JWT with any set of claims, impersonating any user, and can potentially extract all their data - without knowing the password.

How to use JWT for (stateless) authentication while eliminating the risk of an attacker using a stolen private key to impersonate any user without knowing their password?

Answer (score 0):

This question should be moved to https://security.stackexchange.com . Lots of similar questions there with good [answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/where-to-store-a-server-side-encryption-key).

You're making a number of assumptions when going from "the signing key must be" available to "available" means it's "stored on the server" to "attacker can who obtains access to the key". Sure, if you store the private key in a plaintext file on a filesystem with public read, that's one threat model. If you have the key in, say, a HSM that's a whole different animal.

Broad answer: there are a number of key management best practices. For example, [OWASP cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Key_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html) has some recommendations:

> - Developers must understand where cryptographic keys are stored within
>     the application. Understand what memory devices the keys are stored
>     on.
> - Keys must be protected on both volatile and persistent memory,
>     ideally processed within secure cryptographic modules.
> - Keys should
>     never be stored in plaintext format.
> - Ensure all keys are stored in
>     cryptographic vault, such as a hardware security module (HSM) or
>     isolated cryptographic service.

...and so on.

You can also prepare for a worst-case scenario of your key being stolen by considering a more benign use case of rotating the keys.